# Jordan decomposition of tracial functionals on a C*-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a C*-algebra, and let $\phi \in \mathfrak{A}^*$ be a self-adjoint bounded linear functional on $\mathfrak{A}$. Then there exists a unique pair $\phi^+, \phi^-$ of positive bounded linear functionals on $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\phi = \phi^+ - \phi^-$ and $\| \phi \| = \left\| \phi^+ \right\| - \left\| \phi^- \right\|$.

My question is: If $\phi$ is tracial (i.e. $\phi(xy)=\phi(yx)$ for all $x, y \in \mathfrak{A}$), then are $\phi^+, \phi^-$ necessarily tracial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\mathfrak{A}$ is unital, every algebra element is a linear combination of unitaries, so a linear functional being tracial is equivalent to $\phi = \phi \circ \operatorname{Ad} u$ for every unitary $u$. In this case, for every unitary $u$ we have

$$
\phi = \phi \circ \operatorname{Ad} u = \phi^+ \circ \operatorname{Ad} u - \phi^- \circ \operatorname{Ad} u.
$$

By the uniqueness of the decomposition you have $\phi^\pm = \phi^\pm \circ \operatorname{Ad} u$ and so $\phi^{\pm}$ are tracial.

Answer (score 0):

By 1.14.3. Theorem. in "[$C^*$-algebras and $W^*$-algebras](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540636335)" we have $\phi^+(x)=\phi(px)=\phi(xp)$ for a projection $p$ in $\mathfrak A^{**}$. Therefore
$$\phi^+(xy)=\phi(pxy)=\phi(ypx)=\phi(pypx)=\phi^+(yx)$$